# How long after plugging a tire before I test it?

Tags: tires

I just plugged a lawn mower tire with one of the rope plugs + rubber cement.  How long should I wait before I reinflate and re-test for leaks?  Hour, longer?

Comment: It was the rope plugs, but I believe it just came with rubber cement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon as I put the plug in and cut it off flush with the tread, I will fill the tire. I've never had one come out or have a problem ... and I've done *a lot* of them.